# Upgrade Jackrabbit 1.3 to Jackrabbit 2.1.1

Tags: java, upgrade, backwards-compatibility, lucene, jackrabbit

In my project I need to change Jackrabbit 1.3 to Jackrabbit 2.1.1. My work is to work for queries. Please suggest me if there are changes in index format and query format. Lucene 2.4 is used in  Jackrabbit 2.1.1 while in Jackrabbit 1.3 Lucene 2.2 is used.

Answer (score 2):

Lets divide your upgrade into the following parts:

- Upgrade 1.3 to 1.5 (see [Class IndexMigration](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.2/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/query/lucene/IndexMigration.html)):

  > IndexMigration implements a utility that migrates a Jackrabbit 1.4.x index to version 1.5. Until version 1.4.x, **indexes** used the character '' to separate the name of a property from the value. As of Lucene 2.3 this does not work anymore. See LUCENE-1221. Jackrabbit >= 1.5 uses the character '[' as a separator. Whenever an index is opened from disk, a quick check is run to find out whether a migration is required. See also JCR-1363 for more details.
- Upgrade 1.5 to 2.0.0 (see [RELEASE-NOTES.txt](http://archive.apache.org/dist/jackrabbit/2.0.0/RELEASE-NOTES.txt)):

  > Backwards compatiblity
  >
  > Jackrabbit 2.0 is **designed to be compatible** with existing Jackrabbit
  >   1.x clients and repositories. The main **exceptions** to this goal are:
  >
  > - Removal of deprecated classes and features. Jackrabbit 2.0 is not
  >     backwards compatible with client code that used classes or features
  >     that had been deprecated during the 1.x release cycle. Most notably
  >     the temporary org.apache.jackrabbit.api.jsr283 interfaces have been
  >     removed in favor of the official JCR 2.0 API in javax.jcr.
  > - Repositories that have used the new JSR 283 security features included
  >     as a development preview in Jackrabbit 1.5 and 1.6 may face problems
  >     when upgrading to Jackrabbit 2.0. See especially [JCR-1944](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCR-1944) and [JCR-2313](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCR-2313)
  >     for more details.
  > - The JCR-RMI layer no longer implements the Jackrabbit API extensions.
  >     Code that uses JCR-RMI with distributed transactions or for administration
  >     operations like creating workspaces or registering node types needs to
  >     be updated accordingly.
  > - The JCR-RMI layer in Jackrabbit 2.0 only supports JCR 2.0 repositories.
  >     To access a JCR 1.0 repository implementation like Jackrabbit 1.x over
  >     RMI, you need to use the 1.x versions of JCR-RMI.
- Upgrade 2.0.0 to 2.1.1 (2.x branch is positioned to have a stable API):

  > This is Apache Jackrabbit 2.0.0, a **fully compliant** and production-ready
  >   implementation of the Content Repository for Java Technology API, version 2.0

See also compatibility tables for [Jackrabbit](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/java/versions/jackrabbit.html) and [Lucene](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/java/versions/lucene.html) APIs.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to migrate from Jackrabbit 1.x to 2.x. Probably the best documentation can be found in the [Jackrabbit Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/FrontPage), one the [Backup and Migration](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/BackupAndMigration) page.

Comment: Is jackrabbit oak dead? Why does the jcr-oak documentation say to use OSGI when using RDB document storage? Is anyone other than legacy software still using OSGI? Why use OSGI? Is OSGI dead? all the documentation seems to be from 2010-2015. Any thoughts on this appreciated.

Comment: Jackrabbit Oak is absolutely not dead, why do you think so? Why use OSGI: that is a separate question; I use Oak without OSGI. The documentation (and code) is updated regularly, e.g. https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit-oak/commits/trunk/oak-doc/src/site/markdown/nodestore/segment/overview.md

Comment: It would be great if the jackrabbit-oak RDB documentation didn't push using OSGI:  https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/nodestore/document/rdb-document-store.html

Comment: @WallaceHowery I'm afraid I don't have any stake in this area... but because this is an open source project, I think it should be possible to support what you would like, if you submit a PR!