# jackrabbit. migrate from 1.x to 2.x

Tags: migration, jackrabbit

We have jackrabbit repository 1.6.0 version.
We need to migrate to 2.2.7 version.
What is the best way to do that without missing content?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is probably to export to XML, and then re-import. Other solutions are [documented in the Jackrabbit wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/BackupAndMigration).

Comment: Thanks export-import almost work for us. Nodes just lost their virsion history, but we can live with it.

Answer (score 0):

Answers to ["Upgrade Jackrabbit 1.3 to Jackrabbit 2.1.1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377169/upgrade-jackrabbit-1-3-to-jackrabbit-2-1-1) question may help. See also [this compatibility report](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/java/versions/jackrabbit.html) for the Jackrabbit library between 1.6.4 to 2.0.0 versions.

[image]